# PRESTO (Athena) counting distinct cases, and adding rows as 1 string for string search

Tags: sql, amazon-athena, presto

For lack of better words, I have this table called 'questionnaire':

```
user_id | question          answer
--------------------------|-----------  
A       | can you sing?   |Yes
A       | can you dance?  |Yes
A       | did you eat?    |No
B       | can you sing?   |No
C       | can you sing?   |Yes
C       | did you eat?    |Yes
```

I want to write a query that shows me this below. I know how to make the last 3 columns, but I need help taking care of the "can sing & dance case" , as in how many distinct people can sing AND dance.
So I want an output like this:

```
DESIRED OUTPUT:

can sing & dance | can sing | can dance |total user_ids
-----------------|----------|-----------|---------------
 1               | 2        |1          |3
```

What is the BEST method to go about this?
Originally, I was using just SUM(CASE(WHEN ....THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) for the 'can sing' and 'can dance' and COUNT(distinct user_id), but this does not help with the 'can sing and dance' (column 1 from desired output) case, unless I'm doing something wrong.

My table is structured just as the example. Users can answer how many questions they want (they don't have to answer all questions, they can just answer as many as they want)

Answer can only be 'Yes' or 'No'

I was thinking maybe if I can somehow write like a subquery to make it look like this:

```
user_id|question& answer
-------|---------
A      | can you sing?Yes,can you dance?Yes,did you eat?Yes
B      | can you sing?No
C      | can you sing?Yes,did you eat?Yes
```

And then to search the "question&answer" column using some regular expression trick to count?

I am asking for the BEST approach. In the end, i want COUNTS, and if i could get a very helpful hint :) (pls ^-^)

I am using Amazon Athena, so PRESTO SQL

Answer (score 0):

Not pretty.

the inner select  gets all needed data for every user.

The outer SELECT determnes the number of users that apply

```
SELECT
SUM(IF(`can you sing?` = 1 AND `can you dance?` = 1,1,0)) AS 'can you sing and dance?',
SUM(`can you sing?`) AS 'can you sing?',
SUM(`can you dance?`) AS 'can you dance?',
SUM(`did you eat?`) AS 'did you eat?',
(SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT `user_id`) FROM questionnaire) AS 'total user_ids'
FROM
(SELECT
    SUM(       CASE
       WHEN `question` = 'can you sing?' AND  `answer` =  'Yes' THEN 1
        ELSE  0 END)) AS 'can you sing?',
    SUM(   CASE
       WHEN `q`question` = 'can you dance?' AND `answer` =  'Yes' THEN  1 ELSE 0 END)) AS 'can you dance?',
    SUM(   CASE
       WHEN `q`question` = 'did you eat?' AND `answer` =  'Yes' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)) AS 'did you eat?'
FROM
questionnaire
GROUP BY `user_id`) t1
```